# Changing the Hover to Click functionality using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Builtby will FlipBook.

**HTML**

```
<div id="mybook">
    <div title="This is a page title"> 
        <h3>Yay, Page 1!</h3>
    </div>
    <div> 
        <h3>Yay, Page 2!</h3>
    </div>
    <div title="This is another title"> 
        <h3>Yay, Page 3!</h3>
    </div>
    <div> 
        <h3>Yay, Page 4!</h3>
    </div>
    <div title="Hooray for titles!"> 
        <h3>Yay, Page 5!</h3>
    </div>
    <div> 
        <h3>Yay, Page 6!</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(function() {
    $('#mybook').booklet({
        menu: '#custom-menu',
        pageSelector: true
    });
});
```

The Demo is Here:
http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/demos/pageselect

Now I want to change the default behavior of the Page Selector. We are getting the Page options on hover. I want to change it to Click functionality. When I Click on the Page Selector, it should display the Menu. When I click it on again, it should hide the Page selecor..Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below jquery.

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/saranyaciet/YwRab/2/)**

```
$('#mybook').booklet({
    menu: '#custom-menu',
    pageSelector: true,
    manual:   false,
    hovers:   false,
    overlays: true
});
```

In your booklet.js file, change the line no. 577 //add hover effects to the below one

```
// add click effects
pageSelector.on('click.booklet', function () {
    if (pageSelectorList.stop().height() == pageSelectorHeight)
    {
         pageSelectorList.stop().animate({height: 0, paddingBottom: 0}, 500);
    }
    else
    {  
         pageSelectorList.stop().animate({height: pageSelectorHeight, paddingBottom: 10}, 500);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. But I want the Page selector (which is on the top of the book with Black color) to be work on click not on hover.

Comment: I don't see any Page selector (which is on the top of the book with Black color)

Comment: It is located on the top right hand side of the booklet with title"1-2". plz refer: http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/demos/pageselect

Comment: Check the updated fiddle, you need to change hover function to click in your booklet.latest.js file http://jsfiddle.net/saranyaciet/YwRab/2/

Comment: Check the edited answer and find for line no. 577 with comment //add hover effects in your booklet.js plugin

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

//setter

```
$(".selector").booklet( "option", "hovers", false );
```